# How do you access non-standard attributes in Firefox JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, cross-browser

Basically in IE you can do something like this:

```
<img metaDataAtt="type5" src="..." id="tag1"/>
```

and then in the JavaScript do something like

```
var theImg = document.getElementById("tag1");
alert(theImg.metaDataAtt);
```

However, in firefox you can't. Is there some sort of hack to get around this?

Thanks,
Grae

Comment: Seems like a part of your question is missing.

Comment: hmm your right, I check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('tag1').getAttribute('metaDataAtt');
```

Comment: Just tested it, works for Firefox.  Does it work for IE also?  It seems like it probably will.

Comment: I know this is a little old, but how do you set those attribute from JavaScript?

Comment: @Grae document.getElementById('tag1').setAttribute('metaDataAtt', 'foo');